# Каким образом можно сделать EditText невидимым

Tags: android, java

подскажите, пожалуйста каким образом можно сделать EditText невидимым в процессе работы приложения.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

будет невидимый но место на экране будет занимать

```
editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

исчезнет полностью

Answer (score -2):

```
editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: @Ooo, [**в ответе Gorets**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/207686/199934) это написано, и он более подробный. Спасибо.